# React Native + Axios: Network error only on android device

Tags: react-native, axios

I'm developping a React Native App connected to my Api with Axios. When I'm on emulator my calls ork fine, but when I'm using my android phone I'm getting "Network Error".

I already searched for solutions, but not found my case. I already tried to put android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in the Manifest but this doesn't work.

My server is a local server.

Here is my code to connect to the API:

```
import Axios from 'axios';
const devURL = 'http://my_ip:8080';
const apiConfigure = '/api/';
const baseURL = devURL + apiConfigure;
console.log('baseUrl', baseURL);

export interface IResponse {
  success: boolean;
  error?: string;
}

export const rtv = Axios.create({
  baseURL,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' },
});
```

And here is an api call example:

```
export const fetchToken = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<IToken> => {
  try {
    const {data} = await rtv.post('auth/signin', {email:email, password});
    console.log('data', data);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      toastError('Error in connection');
      return null;
  }
};
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm assuming your device is on the same wifi network as your computer?

Comment: Yes on the same network

Comment: Check your proxy